# How to put CirclePageIndicator on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've implemented CirclePageIndicator and worsks fine. But i want to put it on the ActionBar.

This is a screenshot of the app.

[image: Screenshot actual app]

And this is a picture where i want to put the CirclePageIndicator.
[image: Screenshot desired app]

I don't know how to add in the res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml as a Item.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needs put the items together in a RalativeLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_slideshow_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vista_banner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"/>

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vista_especials"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/banner"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```